# What are the ramifications of changing `--port` in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

If I'm running a full node with `--lightserv` enabled for several hundred clients, what are the ramifications of me running geth on a port other than 30303? If I change it to `--port 2345` will I still be able to have outgoing/incoming connections to full nodes so I can sync new blocks? Will LES enabled clients be able to find my node at all?

My full node on 30303 has ~500 connections currently, a separate full node on port 2345 only has about 20.

Separately, I still need full nodes to find me to relay new blocks right, LES clients don't do any relaying?

**Update**: well, light clients can obviously still find me but it appears to be far fewer on the non-standard port. Still not sure why that would be

Port 2345 node:

```
# geth attach http://localhost:8545 --exec 'for(i in admin.peers) { console.log(admin.pe
ers[i].caps) }' | grep -v undefined | sort | uniq -c
      2 eth/62,eth/63
      1 eth/62,eth/63,par/1,par/2,par/3,pip/1
      3 eth/62,eth/63,par/1,par/2,pip/1
     15 les/1,les/2
      1 les/1,les/2,shh/6
```

Port 30303 node:

```
# geth attach http://localhost:8545 --exec 'for(i in admin.peers) { console.log(admin.pe
ers[i].caps) }' | grep -v undefined | sort | uniq -c
      3 eth/62,eth/63
      1 eth/62,eth/63,par/1,par/2,par/3
      5 eth/62,eth/63,par/1,par/2,pip/1
      2 eth/63
    389 les/1,les/2
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the port in geth will have ramifications on the interactions of the Ethereum node with the rest of the network. When the port is changed, the node will no longer be able to communicate with other nodes on the default port, meaning it will no longer be able to sync the blockchain or join the network. Additionally, any applications connected to the node will no longer be able to communicate with it unless they are configured to use the new port.